# Can I use chef as a PaaS deployment orchestrator to deploy multiple drupal sites?

Tags: drupal, deployment, chef-infra, cookbook

*"I do apologize prior to asking this dumb question "*

So, my idea is to have :

- A chef server
- N nodes

On each node; i'll define a basic role; like "NodeRole" which will have apache,php,mysql

Then, i'd like to be able to deploy 'à la demande' multiple virtualhosts each containing a full drupal install.

So this new role will have some attributes like :

```
"username"
"password"
"URL"
```

When 'deploying' this; it will :

```
- Add an entry to apache virtual host configuration
- Create a user account with provided password
- Create a database user with provided password
- Install drupal with the provided credentials
```

How can I do this 'dynamically' without having to create a txt file each time I want to deploy a new site.

Is it possible to interact with the chef server api and say something like "deploy www.example.com john mypassword" ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you set on a chef solution? What you want sounds similar to Aegir: http://www.aegirproject.org/

Comment: Aegir is nice; but, i want it to be a little more flexible ... i won't be using only drupal but several other frameworks; drupal is just a starter ... sorry if the question wasn't that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chef is a pull model it's up to the clients to request their configuration. If you want to push you'll have to inject something else in to allow you to do that. A command dispatcher which can invoke the client to contact the server when you want.

If you want to do the same thing over and over it feels like creating a LWRP http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Lightweight+Resources+and+Providers+(LWRP) might be your best bet. You could then pass into it the variables you have and that way the code doesn't need reproduced X times.

If you didn't want to have to create new recipes for each install one other option would be to use the JSON mash capabilites in the attributes object and loop through a collection of objects creating the installs. This way it's data driven but personally I would look to use different recipes per install as it would probably be more transparent to people viewing the runlist.

An example of using the attributes mash is shown below. You could acheive this with a databag as well. In this case you could then update the JSON representation in a file and upload with knife or make the changes in the UI. Again I would recommend a recipe per site for transparency but that would lead to code/updating runlists etc

Your attribute json object would look a bit like this or similar

```
"drupal_Sites" : {
    "site1": { "username": "dave", "password" :"password123", "URL":"www.madeup.com" },
    "site2": { "username": "dave2", "password" :"password12", "URL":"www.madeup2.com" }
}
```

Then in your recipe it would be something like this

```
node["drupal_sites"].each do | site | 

Install = yourdrupalcookbook_InstallResource "#{site['URL']}" do
    username site['username']
    password site['password']
    deploy site['URL']
    action :nothing 
    provider "yourdrupalcookbook_InstallProvider"
end

Install.run_action(:create)
```

end

Comment: Not sure to understand; i know chef's a pull model; so each time i'll modify a node's role on the server; clients will pull new changes right ? and it does that on a 30 minutes basis.

Comment: What is 'json mash capabilites' ? Can you provide a simple example ?

Comment: The comment about pull model was just regarding contacting the chef-server api that the best you could do is propogate changes that would then be taken down on next chef run but apologies for any confusion. A mash in chef is basically just a hash in Ruby with a little extension will update answer to include an example

Comment: thanks; i now understand. Regarding the REST api; can i send a json with attributes (as you explained above with your code) that can 'trigger' the update of the nodes ?

Comment: You can use the REST API or knife to upload/update environment or role attributes and pass a json file with it yep. The next run of the client would see the updated attributes

Comment: what is "yourdrupalcookbook_InstallResource" and "yourdrupalcookbook_InstallProvider" ?